# How can I typedef boost::function<T> requiring a type argument?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, typedef, boost-function

Piecing together some examples I found on stackoverflow, I'd like to do the following:

```
template<typename T>
using FuncPtr = boost::function< int (const T) >;
```

Perhaps to later use it like so:

```
template<typename T>
build_fancy_lookup_table( string key, FuncPtr<T> fp);
```

However, it doesn't appear to work.  I get the following error message:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here?  I'd like to be able to typedef/alias the boost::function expression to aid in coding.

Here's how I am compiling:

```
prompt> g++ foo.cpp
prompt> g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
```

thanks.

Comment: `using`  aliases are a C++11 feature.

Comment: ... so you need to enable C++11 support in your compiler, which might mean using an option like `-std=c++11`

Comment: Yes, you guys are right.  Thanks.  Please post answer.  So I can check mark it.  I was compiling with g++ no arguments.  Let me add that to my post....